# open .dat file in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a .dat file and I want to generate the content in python, thus I use the following code:

```
import numpy as np

bananayte=np.fromfile("U04_banana-ytest.dat",dtype=float)
print(bananayte)
```

However, my initial data should be like "1.0000000e+00", while the output is like "1.39804066e-76". What happened? and what should I do to get the correct value? Thanks!

Comment: that looks more like your initial value maybe is close to zero? why do you think its 1?

Comment: I opened the data file in a text editor and it is a label set of +1 and -1.

Comment: how bout posting the first few lines from the file?

Comment: @jiayi without all the code it's quite hard to say, even tough I suppose numpy being a math oriented lib is using higher precision numers, instead of int, doubles therefore the output number has higher precision, anyway can you post all the relevant code?

Comment: but there's no other codes for now! this works alone... just to see the data.

Comment: You have a text file opened as binary.

Comment: all right now. I simply use open("U04_banana-ytest.dat") and then bananayte.read() and now it works! thanks!